# Join com tres ou mais tabelas com lambda

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Fiz essa expressão usando Lambda e 2 tabelas.

```
var resultado = db.T_TarefaParceiro.Join(
                db.T_OsParceiro,
                t1 => t1.IDTarefaParceiro,
                t2 => t2.IDTarefaParceiro,
                (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                .Where(a => a.t1.IDTarefaParceiro == a.t2.IDTarefaParceiro && a.t2.Is_Tarefa_Fechada == true)
                .Select(i => new { i.t1.CNPJ });
```

Estou com dificuldades de colocar uma terceira ou quarta tabela. Tentei criar mais uma cláusula Join, mas deu erro. Como eu faço?

Comment: Eu adicionei um exemplo logo abaixo, se você quiser algo especifico de seus models informe igual desenho abaixo, que eu escreve o lambda expression dela, mas, pelo exemplo se pode tirar a lógica!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tudo vai depender de como estão os seus relacionamentos e chaves, um exemplo básico seria assim:

Tabelas e relacionamentos

```
Uma Pessoa pode ter ou não vários Telefones e um Telefone possui um Tipo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lambda Expression com 2 Join, ou seja, três tabelas, consequentemente três models:

```cs
using (GenericsContext db = new GenericsContext())
{
    var resultado = db.Pessoas
        .Join(db.Telefones, pessoa => pessoa.PessoaId, telefone => telefone.PessoaId, (pessoa, telefone) => new { pessoa, telefone })
        .Join(db.Tipos, telefone => telefone.telefone.TipoId, tipo => tipo.TipoId, (telefone, tipo) => new { telefone, tipo })
        .Select(x => new
        {                        
            x.telefone.pessoa.PessoaId,
            x.telefone.pessoa.Nome,
            x.tipo.Descricao,
            x.telefone.telefone.Ddd,
            x.telefone.telefone.Numero
        });

    var resultadoToList = resultado.ToList();
}
```

SQL gerado por essa expressão:

```cs
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PessoaId] AS [PessoaId], 
    [Extent1].[Nome] AS [Nome], 
    [Extent3].[Descricao] AS [Descricao], 
    [Extent2].[Ddd] AS [Ddd], 
    [Extent2].[Numero] AS [Numero]
    FROM   [dbo].[Pessoas] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Telefones] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PessoaId] = [Extent2].[PessoaId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tipos] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[TipoId] = [Extent3].[TipoId]
```

Comment: Compreendi meu erro. Quando eu crio a variável lambda para a terceira tabela, eu tenho que chamá-la e depois a outra variável que vou joinar e depois o campo. Quando eu coloquei a terceira e chamei de j1 e quando busquei no intellisence, a opção foi t1 e t2 e achei que isso estava errado. Faltou conhecimento, claro e é o que busco aqui. Obrigado Harry.

Comment: Por nada, que bom que entendeu e foi útil