# Como fazer um join no C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Galera estou com uma dúvida, consigo fazer um comando SQL (Ex.: `select * from T_TABELA`) no meu repositório do C# igual faço no banco, porém gostaria de saber se da para fazer um comando `join` no C# igual faço no banco?

Estava tentando esse comando, mas sempre da erro, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
select * from tblModelo modelo join tblMarca marca on marca.IdMarca = modelo.IdModelo;
```

No meu banco SQL SERVER este comando funciona!

Código no C#:

```
 public List<clsModelo> listar()
        {
            strQuery = "select * from tblModelo join tblMarca on IdMarca = IdModelo";
            List<clsModelo> result = db.Database.SqlQuery<clsModelo>(strQuery).ToList();
            return result;
        }
```

Classe Marca:

```
public class clsMarca

    {
       [Key]
       public int IdMarca { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome da marca")]
       [MinLength(3), MaxLength(50)]
       public string Marca { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<clsModelo> Modelos { get; set; }
    }
```

Classe Modelo:

```
public class clsModelo
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdModelo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Informe o nome do Modelo")]
        [StringLength(40, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome do modelo precisa ter no mínimo 3 letras")]
        public string Modelo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Marca")]
        public int IdMarca { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdMarca")]
        public virtual clsMarca Marca { get; set; }

        List<clsModelo> lstModelo { get; set; }
    }
```

Um erro que aparecia dizia que IdMarca não pertence ao contexto de Modelo, sendo que eu informei q ela é uma chave estrangeira.

Comment: Qual é o erro?.

Comment: Como você está tentando fazer no c#?

Comment: Esse trecho é do SQL ou do C#? Você quer fazer um Join no Linq?

Comment: coloca o código pois em c# existem n maneiras de buscar dados em um DB.

Comment: Este comando Join é o mesmo jeito q estou fazendo no c# e no banco, quais são as maneiras de fazer uma unica busca em duas tabelas?

Comment: Mostre o seu código!

Comment: `strQuery = "select * from tblModelo join tblMarca on marIdMarca = modIdModelo";` essa SQL pode dar problemas tem que colocar os nomes ou alias por isso do problema! Apesar que você não relatou o erro que está retornando ...

Comment: Desculpa, editei a pergunta, vê se da para entender agora.

Comment: Existe uma resposta usando lambda aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17618/join-com-tres-ou-mais-tabelas-com-lambda

Comment: Não seria só assim então: `strQuery = "select * from tblModelo join tblMarca on IdMarca = IdModelo"`;

Comment: Eu estava adaptando para colocar na pergunta e esqueci de alterar

Comment: Não deu certo? qual foi a exceção lançada?

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse link (obs: stackoverflow em ingles): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005095/establish-foreign-key-connection-using-entity-framework-with-sql-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possivelmente o retorno não será do tipo "clsModelo", porque vai conter os campos da tblModelo + tblMarca.

Tenta executar o sql sem usar este cast para o tipo clsModelo. Algo parecido com isso:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery(strQuery).ToList();
```

Comment: SqlQuery está incorreto. O certo seria SqlQuery<TIPO> onde "TIPO" pode ser um objeto ou int ou string etc...