# Relacionar mais de uma coluna com lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda, join

Tenho a consulta abaixo que relaciona somente o ProcessoId. Preciso saber como relacionar as listas processos e processosPendentes por ProcessoId e GrupoId. Já consultei em vários grupos e não obtive uma reposta. Grato.

```
            return processos.Join(
                processosPendentes,
                p => p.ProcessoId,
                pp => pp.ProcessoId,
                (p, pp) => new Processos
                {
                    ProcessoId = p.ProcessoId,
                    GrupoId = p.GrupoId,
                    Descricao = p.Descricao,
                }

            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Join com tres ou mais tabelas com lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17618/join-com-tres-ou-mais-tabelas-com-lambda)